# Android libraries imported with Gradle impose allowBackup="true" on the entire project

Tags: android

I really need to set `allowBackup="false"` in my project, however, when I try to build I get the stupidest reason ever for build failure - some library is imposing `allowBackup` to `true` in its Manifest and **apparently that gets priority over the project's manifest file**.

So I removed the library (and will somehow try to use another library to achieve what I was using it for) and tried to build again...

.. and yet another library caused the same problem! Now I have to rewrite massive parts of the app just to be able to get rid of `allowBackup="true"`

Is there a way that I can turn it off somehow? Or could I place some code that will erase whatever this so convenient backup is doing at app startup time?